# pyside6 project .exe file created using cx_freeze not opening

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyside6

I have created a UI using PySide6 and QML. I am trying to convert this project to a .exe file. I found this [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8dwNfnxYLo&t=164s). I am using cx_Freeze library to convert the project to .exe file.
Here is my **setup.py file**:

```
import os
import sys

from cx_Freeze import Executable, setup

files = ['api_login_test.py', 'dr_t_app_name.ico', 'qml/']

target = Executable(script='main.py',
                    base='Win32GUI',
                    icon='app_name.ico')

setup(name="Analyzer",
    version="1.0",
    description="Analyzer",
    author="XYZ",
    options={"build_exe":{"include_files":files}},
    executables=[target])
```

qml folder in the project directories contain all the qml files along with an images folder that contains all images for this project.
It is getting built properly without any error, but when I try to run the .exe file, nothing happens. I checked **task manager** there I could see the name of exe in background processes section.
I am using windows 10, python 3.9.x
Can anyone help me sort this out?
Thank you

Comment: use pyinstaller

Comment: @alexpdev thank you for your response. Can you share an example of same? where I can specify what modules and packages to include and exclude.

Comment: Try running exe from debugger (cdb or gdb), it could give some clues about missing libraries or files.

Comment: I tried running the exe file from command prompt, and it was running properly, but when I double click on the file, it is not opening.

Comment: I used pyinstaller  for exe creation. and it worked after tweaking some changes in .spec file.